# PHP captcha not displaying in 000webhost

Tags: php

I am trying to display my captcha image in my website hosted at `000webhost` but it's showing the error:

> imagettftext() [function.imagettftext]: Could not find/open font in
>   /home/a3594760/public_html/captcha1.php on line 20

While I have file MAGENTOB.TTF in the same folder. My code is the same code is working in my localhost but it's shows error when hosted in `000webhost`:

```
<?php
  include_once('includes/session.php');
  $_SESSION['secure']=rand(1000,9999);
  header('content-type:image/jpeg');
  $text=$_SESSION['secure'];

  $font_size=25;
  $image_width=200;
  $image_height=40;

  $image=imagecreate($image_width,$image_height);
  imagecolorallocate($image,255,255,255);
  $text_color=imagecolorallocate($image,0,0,0);
  for($x=1;$x<=40;$x++)
  {
    $x1=rand(1,120);
    $x2=rand(1,120);
    $y1=rand(1,120);
    $y2=rand(1,120);
    imageline($image,$x1,$y1,$x2,$y2,$text_color);
  }
  imagettftext($image,$font_size,0,15,30,$text_color ,'MAGNETOB.TTF',$text);
  imagejpeg($image);

?>
```

What's wrong?

Comment: Give the full path, does that work (depends on the GD lib I think).

Answer (score 0):

What is your localhost setup? And what is the setup at `000webhost`?

My first guess is that there might be a case sensitivity issue. Where your file name might be `MAGNETOB.TTF` in your file but somehow `magnetob.ttf` on the filesystem.

Another issue might be the filepath needing to be full specified. So it is something like:

```
/path/to/my/font/on/web/MAGNETOB.TTF
```

Final idea is connected to file permissions. Can the webserver read the file?